# Is there a way to populate a data structure from a text file in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, database

I am trying to use vis.js to draw out network topologies. The required format for entering nodes and edges is as follows:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]);
    var edges = new vis.DataSet([
        {from: 1, to: 3},
        {from: 1, to: 2},
        {from: 2, to: 4},
        {from: 2, to: 5}
    ]);
```

I want to know how I can enter this data directly from a text file. I have two separate .txt files for the nodes and edges. I need to read them and populate the nodes and edges variables in my js script.

The nodes .txt file looks like this

```
{id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
{id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
{id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
{id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
{id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
```

And the edges .txt file looks like this

```
{from: 1, to: 3},
{from: 1, to: 2},
{from: 2, to: 4},
{from: 2, to: 5}
```

Please share the code and thanks in advance.

Comment: This largely depends how you run your code, if its a simple html page then you can just add txt files in the same folder and use fetch() to get the contents and parse it.

Comment: Hi Narendran. Is the reason for your syntax that you expect it to be easier to load as JSON? Would it be possible for you to generate valid .json files?

Comment: Where should these text files be stored? On the local machine, so that the user would need to drop them somewhere? Or should they be loaded automatically from the machine? Are they on the server?

Comment: This is tagged with `database`... can you explain how this relates to a database? Do you have a server application? Are these texts actually generated from a database? Then you would need to rethink the process and omit those text files all together.

Comment: The nodes and edges will be generated by a different module. As of now all the files are saved locally. There is no particular reasoner choosing .txt file. I am new to JS so I just saved the nodes and edges as a .txt file.
Yes, I can generate a .JSON file. 
So once this file has been generated locally, after I hit a button, the nodes and edges variables should be populated from that file. 
It has to happen after I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a JSON file for this. Not only will you get syntax highlighting and formatting in your IDE, but it can also be imported very easily using Node.js: `require('./your-data-file.json')` and will be parsed to a JS object out of the box.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    { "id": 1, "label": "Node 1"},
    { "id": 2, "label": "Node 2"},
    { "id": 3, "label": "Node 3"},
    { "id": 4, "label": "Node 4"},
    { "id": 5, "label": "Node 5"}
  ]
}
```